# nginx rst packet after sending http response

Tags: sockets, nginx, tcp

I´m using nginx 1.10.3.

What I´m trying to force is the following scenario:

1.2.3. Client <--> Server | TCP 3 way tcp handshake

4. Client --> Server | HTTP GET
5. Server --> Client | TCP ACK
6. Server --> Client | HTTP response
7. **Server --> Client | TCP RST, ACK**

I try to provoke sending an RST packet after responding the http get request. 
For this purpose I set the "lingering_close off" configuration parameter in the nginx_conf file, but without success. Is there another way to provoke this kind of scenario?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share it with us!

Comment: First of all I tried to configure this issue with the lingering_close parameter the nginx.conf. with no success.

While searching through the sources, I only see one place where the setsockopt(SO_LINGER) parameter is set (ngx_http_request --> function ngx_http_free_request).

The problem is I can´t see any place where to configure it or set this option while sending the http response.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we also meet similar scenario: there are many 'Broken pipe' errors in our application error log.

And after analysis of tcp transport info, we found sometimes nginx will send a 'RST' immediately after it send FIN to upstream server. Final conclusion, the reason of this behavior we think is when the client close the connection to the nginx, the nginx will close the relative upstream connection and not wait the upstream to execute the rest task.

So according to the nginx document, we aad the config `proxy_ignore_client_abort on` to the nginx config file. Reference: [http://nginx.org/](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_client_abort)

p.s. Our nginx version is 1.12.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.